# OAuth: Is it ok to return access token as json?

Tags: javascript, json, oauth, jsonp

When I return the request token (I am the server), I send the values in the body of the response:

```
oauth_token=946ccd316c&oauth_token_secret=395cfee8ca&oauth_callback_confirmed=true
```

I am trying to figure out if it'd be possible to do the dance over `jsonp`. Signing and requesting works fine, but as the body isn't json, the response fails during parsing.

So, I could reply with the body coded as jsonp insted (if the client requested it), like this:

```
callback({oauth_token:'946ccd316c',oauth_token_secret:'395cfee8ca',oauth_callback_confirmed:true})
```

And it would probably work. My questions are:

**Would this break all the standards? Am I allowed to change the encoding of the body? Is there a better way?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OAuth specification doesn't specify format for sending token. So I think you are good to return it inside JSON object as you have shown.

In fact Google also returns **access_token** inside a JSON object as shown below:

```
response :{
  "access_token" : "ya29S6ZQbiBQpA5Rz8oty00xj-xydfdfddteerer-1eM",
  "token_type" : "Bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3600
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the OAuth 2.0 standard - the RFC is found [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).  For the required access token behavior, you'd be interested in sections 4.4.2 (access token request) and 4.4.3 (access token response).  The format of the body for the response is not specified; in fact, there's an example shown in the spec of an access token response encoded in JSON.  So long as you set your content type to application/json, and use the required parameter names, you're good to go.